# jquery: Fill textarea with unescaped html in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am attempting to store html code in a textarea field using jquery with the following code:

```
var text ="<p>Hello, my name is Sam</p>";
var textarea = d.createElement( 'textarea' ); // Creates textarea to store text
div.appendChild( textarea );
textarea.innerHTML  = text; 
// $("textarea").val(modified_clipboard_text); // same issue
console.log( textarea.innerHTML ); // output should not be escaped html
```

The issue is, html strings are transformed to escaped entities (at least in Chrome). For example: `<p>` is transformed to `&lt;p&gt;`

Comment: You want to see Html in textarea?

Comment: Sorry, no. I want to store html code in a textarea for latter usage using `textarea.select();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQuery solution**

You're using jquery so why not using the magic :

```js
var text ="<p>Hello, my name is Sam</p>";

$('#container').append('<textarea></textarea>');
$('#container textarea').val(text);

$('#select-btn').click(function() {
    $('#container textarea').select();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
</br>
<button id='select-btn'>Select</button>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be right. I am missing something else or I don't know how to explain it, but I want to be able to paste the copied text (after some jquery modifications) in a rich text editor (like http://ckeditor.com/demo or MS-Word). Actually, if I paste the copied text from your example, this is pasted: `<p>Hello, my name is Sam</p>`, and not the formatted text. For example, if I copy and paste `<p>Hello my name is <strong>Sam</strong></p>`, I want this pasted: Hello my name is **Sam**. Sorry, my fault. I will select your answer if nothing else comes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function htmlUnescape(encodedString){
    return $("<p/>").html(encodedString).text(); 
}
```

Like

```
var text ="<p>Hello, my name is Sam</p>";
var textarea = d.createElement( 'textarea' ); // Creates textarea to store text
div.appendChild( textarea );
textarea.innerHTML  = text; 
// $("textarea").val(modified_clipboard_text); // same issue
console.log( htmlUnescape(textarea.innerHTML) ); // output should not be escaped html
```

Comment: Thanks. I used console.log only to illustrate the issue. I need to use the content stored in the textarea latter. The user selects html code, the html code is stored in textarea, latter, the html code is used by another function. I need to use `textarea.select();` in that function, and the html characters are escaped.